# Incorrect props passed to child component on pages 2+ of react-table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-modal, react-table

In an instance of [react-table](https://github.com/react-tools/react-table), I am adding a button to each row to launch a [react-modal](https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal). This works as expected on the first page of the table, but on subsequent pages the incorrect `id` prop is passed into my custom `ReactModal`'s `listId`. The `id` that is passed seems to be the one of the row in the same position on the first page of the table. So, the modal components in the first position of pages 2+ receive the `id` prop of the row in the first position on the first page.

I think the line in question is in `Home` below where `Cell: (row: any) => <ListDetailsModal listId={row.value} />,`. The value of `{row.value}` doesn't seem  to work correctly on pages of the table that are not the first.

How can I ensure the correct `id` is passed into `ListDetailsModal`'s `listId` on all pages of `Home`'s `ReactTable`?

Links: [Live Demo](https://beta.filterlists.com/)
 | [Source](https://github.com/collinbarrett/FilterLists/blob/master/src/FilterLists.Web/ClientApp/components/Home.tsx)

**react-table component class:**

```
export class Home extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, IFilterListsState> {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { filterLists: [], loading: true };
        fetch("https://api.filterlists.com/v1/lists")
            .then(response => response.json() as Promise<IFilterListSummaryDto[]>)
            .then(data => { this.setState({ filterLists: data, loading: false }); });
    }

    render() {
        const contents = this.state.loading
            ? <p>
                  <em>Loading...</em>
              </p>
            : Home.renderFilterListsTable(this.state.filterLists);
        return <div>
                   {contents}
               </div>;
    }

    private static renderFilterListsTable(filterLists: IFilterListSummaryDto[]) {
        return <ReactTable
                   data={filterLists}
                   defaultSorted={[{id: "name"}]}
                   columns={[
                       {
                           Header: "Name",
                           accessor: "name",
                           filterable: true,
                           filterMethod: (filter: any, row: any) => row[filter.id].toUpperCase().includes(filter.value.toUpperCase()),
                           sortMethod: (a: any, b: any) =>  a.toUpperCase() > b.toUpperCase() ? 1 : -1
                       },
                       {
                           Header: "Details",
                           accessor: "id",
                           sortable: false,
                           Cell: (row: any) => <ListDetailsModal listId={row.value} />,
                           style: { textAlign: "center" },
                           width: 100
                       }
                   ]}/>;
    }
}
```

**react-modal component class**:

```
export default class ListDetailsModal extends React.Component<any, any> {
    private readonly listId: any;

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { showModal: false, loading: true };
        this.listId = props.listId;
        this.handleOpenModal = this.handleOpenModal.bind(this);
        this.handleCloseModal = this.handleCloseModal.bind(this);
    }

    handleOpenModal() {
        this.setState({ showModal: true });
        fetch(`https://api.filterlists.com/v1/lists/${this.listId}`)
            .then(response => response.json() as Promise<IFilterListDetailsDto[]>)
            .then(data => { this.setState({ filterListDetails: data, loading: false }); });
    }

    handleCloseModal() {
        this.setState({ showModal: false });
    }

    render() {
        const contents = this.state.loading
            ? null
            : <ReactModal
                  isOpen={this.state.showModal}
                  onRequestClose={this.handleCloseModal}
                  shouldCloseOnOverlayClick={true}>
                  <FilterListDetails details={this.state.filterListDetails}/>
                  <button onClick={this.handleCloseModal} className="btn btn-danger btn-block push-to-bottom">Close</button>
              </ReactModal>;
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.handleOpenModal} className="btn btn-primary btn-block">Details</button>
                {contents}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: pointers from react-table chat I am trying: "I suspect you will need to implement `componentDIdReceiveProps` in your modal wrapper component. This is because the component is already mounted so the `constructor` is not going to be called again until it is destroyed then mounted again. or possibly `comonentDidMount` - that’s what I would be tinkering with and dropping in `console.log` statements to see what we being called when the page changes. the other thing you might want to consider is giving your component a `key` that you generate uniquely for each cell, that might force React to redraw"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, the problem was that the already rendered component was not getting updated with the new props when the user changed pages of the table. All that was needed was adding this to capture the new props.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps: any) {
    this.listId = nextProps.listId;
}
```

Comment: If I could give this 100 up-votes I would - thanks for sharing the solution!